# Unable to execute sonarqube scanner with jenkins

Tags: sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline, sonarscanner

I am unable to execute the sonarqube scanner with Jenkins pipeline script.
sonarqube scanner version  : 3.3.0

Please suggest.

```
stage('SonarQube analysis 3') {
     steps {
      withSonarQubeEnv('sonarqube') {
      echo "${SONAR_HOST_URL}"
      sh "/var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/sonarQScanner/bin/sonar-scanner -Dsonar.host.url=${SONAR_HOST_URL} -Dsonar.login=${SONAR_USERNAME} -Dsonar.password = ${SONAR_PASSWORD} -Dsonar.projectName=HelloWorldMavenProj -Dsonar.projectVersion=4.0 -Dsonar.projectKey=HelloWorldMavenProjKey -Dsonar.sources=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/SonarPipelineTest"
}}}
```

Error :

```
/var/lib/jenkins/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/sonarQScanner/bin/sonar-scanner -Dsonar.host.url=http://xxxxx:9000 -Dsonar.login=admin -Dsonar.password = admin -Dsonar.projectName=HelloWorldMavenProj -Dsonar.projectVersion=4.0 -Dsonar.projectKey=HelloWorldMavenProjKey -Dsonar.sources=/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/SonarPipelineTest
```

**ERROR: Unrecognized option: =**

Comment: Are the spaces in "-Dsonar.password = ${SONAR_PASSWORD}" causing issue?

Comment: No @saurabh14292

Comment: @saurabh14292 i have added all the properies into another file called sonar-project.properties and mapped  -Dproject.settings=sonar-project.properties . its working now